# Need to do a live interview in a noisy place

Tags: phone, microphone

I'm a journalism student and for my next assignement I need to do a broadcast live from a noisy place (a sports bar in the middle of a soccer match) to my partner on the station.

I have a mic, jacked into my phone, but if I use that I can't hear my partner on the station.

Is there any solution that can kill most of the sound? This is a one timer, so a free or really cheap solution will be great (even if the solution is just use the phone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a small, inexpensive adapter that allows you to monitor/hear what you are recording.

The best advice would be to get the microphone as CLOSE to the subject as possible. The closer you can get it, the better will be the signal-to-noise ratio.

You could also experiment with your microphone in a similar noisy environment to perfect your technique and characterize the microphone to see how well it performs at close quarters in high noise situations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What kind of adapter are you thinking of?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_st_price-asc-rank?keywords=microphone+headphone+y+adapter  The problem is that they are so inexpensive, you will pay 5x more just for shipping.

Answer (score 0):

Problem you are trying to deal with is quite nasty.

You have to use microphone which is very directional and gets most of the sound from quite narrow space. Place that mic as close as possible to the mouth. That will reduce unwanted noise.

You can also use some noise cancellation device and secondary microphone that will pick up surrounding noise and then use it to cancel noise picked up by other microphone.

In theory, technique is quite simple: picked up noise is inverted and mixed with signal picked up by main microphone. As both signals would be in opposite phase they will vastly reduce each other, leaving only wanted signal, in your case, voice of person you are interviewing.

You will easily find more information and products that can help by searching Internet by terms "noise cancellation" and "noise cancellation microphone".

Answer (score -1):

This sort of furry, microphone cover helps a lot when dealing with a lot of wind noise. It also has an awful name that reminds me of an old buddhist saying: "There's nothing more expensive than the head of a dead cat".
[image]

Comment: Those "dead cat" furry covers are great for dealing with wind noise. However, it seems unlikely that @gbianchi is going to be dealing with any wind noise in a noisy sports bar.  His number one technique for getting decent audio is to get his microphone as close to the subject's mouth as possible.  That will be the easiest way of increasing the Signal-to Noise Ratio.  If he wanted to buy or borrow another mic, a highly directional one (like a hyper-cardioid or even a short shotgun) would be of benefit.